# Geoserver Query

Tags: geoserver, vb.net

we are developing two application, the desktop and web application..
we are using vb.net for desktop application and drupal for web application.., what we are trying to achieve is plot a certain shapefile and save it to the database and that shapefile will be then update to the drupal..

is there a script that automatically upload shapefile to the geoserver in vb.net ???

your help is so much appreciated.. :)

Comment: Does the shapefile Store already exist in GeoServer or are you wanting to create the Store on the fly?

Comment: can vb.net make POST requests to a URL? if so use REST.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you can build one using the "GeoServer REST api", and possibly mimick existing code for other languages, there are clients written in Java, Python and so on

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this link might be helpful. It is in C# and I am trying to convert it to the VB.net.

[Upload shapefile using GeoServer REST API and C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27447/upload-shapefile-using-geoserver-rest-api-and-c)